# How to Calculate LRC in Java

Tags: java, parsing, arrays

My message protocol is as follows:

- STX: 0x02
- ETX: 0x03
- DLE: 0x10 (Delimiter used in front of the 0x2, 0x3 or 0x10 which are data bytes and not STX, ETX or DLE).
- DATA: any values that are 0x02, 0x03 or 0x10 are delimited to avoid confusion with STX, ETX and DLE
- LRC: calculates as an 'XOR' and excludes any DLEs and STX but includes ETX. Also, LRC values are not delimited even if they are 0x2, 0x3 or 0x10.

Here is the data test message that I am testing:

```
byte[] testMessage1 = {
    0x02, // STX
    0x10,0x2,0xA,0x10,0x10,0x7,0x8, // Data 02, A, 10, 7, 8
    0x03, // ETX
    0x2^0xA^0x10^0x7^0x8^0x03 // LRC calculated from the data (with the DLE removed) plus the ETX
};
```

Here is the LRC calculation that I have:

```
public static byte calculateLRC(byte[] bytes) {
    byte LRC = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        LRC ^= bytes[i];
    }
    return LRC;
}
```

How would I do the LRC calculation of the test byte message according to the protocol to check if it is a valid message, and the data before it is not corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very broadly speaking, parsing works with a *state* variable, and depending on the next symbol read the state is changed (error being a possible state).

In your protocol, for validating a message, if you think about it logically from the start, you can work out the states.

The first byte must obviously be STX, or it would not be a valid message. After that, you would like to calculate the LRC while also looking for ETX. Once you find the ETX, the next byte must be the LRC. Conditional states, like escaping via DLE can be expressed as different states, too:

```
State 0:
  If Symbol STX -> State 1
  else -> Error
State 1:
  If Symbol = ETX -> State 3
  else if Symbol = DLE -> State 2
  else update LRC
State 2:
  update LRC -> State 1
State 3:
  if Symbol == LRC -> Ok
  else Error
```

Once you have this state transition table, putting it into code shouldn't be terribly difficult.